# How to suppress exception notification from Glue job?

Tags: amazon-web-services, exception, amazon-redshift, aws-glue

I have a Glue job to write data to a staging table in Redshift that had not existed yet, using write_dynamic_frame.from_jdbc_conf. The preactions create the staging table. Everything worked fine, the data is loaded correctly, but the exception of the staging table not exist keep showing up. How can I suppress this exception?

I tried try - except in Python and it didn't help. I just need the exception notification to go away.

*[Edit]_Additional info:

I'm using

```
from_jdbc_conf(
        frame=df,
        catalog_connection=CATALOG_CONNECTION,
        connection_options=jdbc_options,
        transformation_ctx="write_dynamic_frame",
        redshift_tmp_dir=S3_BUCKET_REDSHIFT_TEMP_DIR
         )
```

to write the dataframe df to redshift.

```
jdbc_options = {
        "database": "some_db",
        "dbtable": "staging_table",
        "preactions": f"CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS staging_table (LIKE {_redshift_db_info['TargetTable']})",
        "postactions": query_to_insert_from_stageing_table_to_target_table,
        "aws_iam_role": REDSHIFT_JDBC_IAM
    }
```

Correct me if I'm wrong, it seems like the df is first load to staging_table connected using dbtable, then the preactions is executed, then the query_to_insert_from_stageing_table_to_target_table, which drop the staging table after the insert. The exeption of the staging_table not exist may be because glue tries to connect to the staging_table specified in dbtable before it check the preactions, however it seems like when glue failed to connect to the dbtable, it raises the exception and execute the preactions, then tried to load the df into the staging_table again, because as I check the data is finally insert correctly into the target table. So everything is kinda ok now, What can I do not to see the exception notification in the log, if not possible, is there any other pattern I can follow to execute the flow above?

Comment: Don't suppress the exception? Adjust the glue job to either create the table or check for it's existance and do nothing if it hasn't been created?

Comment: @RyanFisher Thank you! I've add some info about the scope of the issue. I can make another request to redshift to create the staging table if not exists prior to the current write request, but insert to this staging table is concurrent, so in order to guarantee isolation, I'm looking for a way to create the table a single request like above, without the exception raised along of course.